# Confusion about volume of solid bounded by surfaces

Tags: calculus, integration

Smith and Minton 13.5 #26

> Compute the volume of the solid bounded by
>   the given surfaces:
>   $z = x^2, \ z = x + 2, \ y + z = 5 \ $ and $ \ y = −1$

To proceed, I have made three traces.

(1).

[image]

(2).

[image]

(3).

[image]

(1) is $z = x^2, \ z = x + 2$

(2) is $y + z = 5 , \ y=-1$

(3) is by setting $z=z$ with $5-y=x^2, \ 5-y=x+2$, and of course $y=-1$

At this point I am still confused about the bounds of the volume I am seeking.
I think that I would like to start with $\int_{x^2}^{x+2}dz$, but beyond this is unclear as I also must express $z$ in terms of $y$. Is there any way to express this in two separate integrals?

Also, I am mystified about how $x$ and $y$ relate to each other. I have tried in the third image, but it is still unclear to me. Should I be choosing the bounds on top of the red line or under the red line, and how do I fit it with the rest of the integral? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first two sketches (projections onto the $xz$- and $yz$-planes) are good. The projection of the solid onto the $xz$-plane is the region bounded by $z=x^2$ and $z=x+2$, finding the points of intersection leads to the bounds:
$$-1 \le x \le 2 \;,\; x^2 \le z \le x+2$$
You don't need to split the integral since for any point in this region, the lower and upper bound for $y$ are the same.

To see these, imagine rotating your second plot 90° counter-clockwise about the $z$-axis, so that the $y$-axis points 'into your screen' (away from you). Place it on top of your first plot, aligning the vertical $z$-axis. It should become clear that with respect to $y$, the solid starts at $y=-1$ and runs until you bump into the plane given by $y+z=5 \iff y = 5-z$, so you get:
$$\int_{-1}^2 \int_{x^2}^{x+2} \int_{-1}^{5-z} \,\mbox{d}y\,\mbox{d}z\,\mbox{d}x$$